# Jacobian for term that contains component of a vector

Tags: calculus

I have problems wrapping my head around calculating the jacobian for a term that contains a sum where one summand is a component of the vector.

For completeness, the problem arises when trying to calculate the jacobian for geometric residuals in DVO camera tracking.

$r_i = Z_2(w(\xi, x_i)) - [w(\xi, x_i)]_z$ with $[.]_z$ is taking the 3rd element of the 3x1 vector $w(\xi, x_i)$ and the depth image $Z_2$ that contains pixels $x_i$.

$J_i = \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial \xi}$

I calculated the first part of the sum that corresponds to the $Z_2$ part, but I have trouble deriving the second part with $[...]_z$.

Do I just calculate the Jacobian for $w$ and then take the 3rd element of it?

Comment: 1. what is $Z_{2}$ supposed to mean? 2. It might make more sense to write $w(\xi,x_{i}) \cdot \hat{z}$ to denote the third component of the vector.

Comment: 1. Its an image. I edite the question. 2. With $\hat{z} = (0, 0, 1)^T$?

Comment: As it stands, your question doesn't make sense. Telling me $Z_{2}$ is 'an image' means nothing to me, though if you have already computed the partial derivative of it then I suppose it doesn't matter. It seems like you just need to compute $$\partial_{\xi} r_{i} = \partial_{\xi} (Z_{2}(w)) - \partial_{\xi} w \cdot \hat{z}$$

Comment: Okay, depth image implies that it maps pixels to scalars. So $Z_2(x): R^2 \rightarrow R$. So its really as simple as taking the Jacobians that I calculated anyways for the first part and multiply them with $\hat{z}$. Thanks!